# rename a zend module with routes

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I have a route to rename the 'items' module to 'products', and it works in most cases, but not when there is no controller or action explicitly set in the url. For example, `example.com/products` does not work, while `example.com/items` does, and is the same as `example.com/products/index/index`. Any ideas how to fix it, or to make controllers and actions optional?

```
$router->addRoute('item-alias', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('products/:controller/:action', array(
    'module'=>'items'
)));
```

---

**Edit:**

It seems to work when I changed it to

```
$router->addRoute('item-alias', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('products/:controller/:action/*', array(
    'module'=>'items'
    'controller'=>'index',
    'action'=>'index'
)));
```

The '*' allows additional optional parameters to be appended, e.g. `example.com/products/index/index/page/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set default values for controller and action. That way they will be optional parameters and can be skipped.